# How to define latent Markov models using LMest and seqHMM

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to estimate mixture Latent Markov models (sometimes also called mixture hidden Markov models) using `R`. There are a couple of suitable packages. I am currently testing [`LMest`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04448) and [`seqHMM`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seqHMM/vignettes/seqHMM.pdf). At the moment, I am trying to understand how both packages define and set the number of latent states or latent classes and the accompanying emission and transition probabilities.
`LMest` seems to define latent classes `k1` or latent states `k2` as direct arguments of its commands (e.g. `est_lm_mixed`). Whereas `seqHMM` uses lists of matrices for transition probabilities (k1 x k1) and emission probabilities (k2 x observed states) which must be properly defined so that you get the wanted number latent states and latent classes.

Because of these differences in syntax, I find it hard to estimate the same models using both packages.
Here is a first example code from the `LMest` documentation:

```
library(LMest)
data(data_criminal_sim)
out = long2wide(data_criminal_sim,"id","time","sex",
                c("y1","y2","y3","y4","y5","y6","y7","y8","y9","y10"),aggr=T,full=999)  
XX = out$XX
YY = out$YY
freq = out$freq
n1 = sum(freq[XX[,1]==1])
n2 = sum(freq[XX[,1]==2])
n = sum(freq)
# fit mixed LM model only for females
YY = YY[XX[,1]==2,,]; freq = freq[XX[,1]==2]
k1 = 2; k2 = 2
res = est_lm_mixed(YY,freq,k1,k2,tol=10^-8)
```

And here is a second example from `seqHMM`:

```
library(TraMineR)
library(seqHMM)
data(biofam)

biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam[, 10:25], start = 15,
                     labels = c("parent", "left", "married", "left+marr", "child",
                                "left+child", "left+marr+child", "divorced"))

sc_emiss <- matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 8)
sc_emiss[1,] <- seqstatf(biofam.seq[, 1:4])[, 2] + 0.1
sc_emiss[2,] <- seqstatf(biofam.seq[, 5:9])[, 2] + 0.1
sc_emiss[3,] <- seqstatf(biofam.seq[, 10:13])[, 2] + 0.1
sc_emiss[4,] <- seqstatf(biofam.seq[, 14:16])[, 2] + 0.1
sc_emiss <- sc_emiss / rowSums(sc_emiss)
# Starting values for the transition matrix
sc_trans <- matrix(
  c(0.80, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05,
    0.05, 0.80, 0.10, 0.05,
    0.05, 0.05, 0.80, 0.10,
    0.05, 0.05, 0.10, 0.80),
  nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
# Starting values for initial state probabilities
sc_inits <- c(0.9, 0.07, 0.02, 0.01)

# Build Model
sc_model <- build_hmm(
  observations = biofam.seq, transition_probs = sc_trans,
  emission_probs = sc_emiss, initial_probs = sc_inits)

# Fit model
sc_fit <- fit_model(sc_model)
sc_fit$model
```

**Question**: Is it possible to "translate" the two example into the syntax from the other package? And if so, how do I do that?